# Using value of variable in javascript to access JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, object, variables

I'm trying to access my pie object using the value of some text in HTML.

However, the code is using the name of the variable as opposed to the value of the variable.

This seems like it should be obviously to me, but it's got me stumped.

Thanks

```
var pie = {

    welfare: {
        title: "Welfare",
        percentage : 24,
        point: 0,
        color: '#601C6B'
    },

    health: {
        title: "Health",
        percentage : 20,
        point: 0,
        color: '#FFAA97'
    },

    state_pensions: {
        title: "State pensions",
        percentage : 13,
        point: 0,
        color: "#9C9C9C"
    }
}


$('.pie_item').click(function(){

var pie_piece = $(this).text();

console.log("this is " + pie_piece);

$(this).closest(".drop_down_button").find('p').text(pie_piece);

console.log(pie.pie_piece);

});
```

Comment: what is pie_piece in the object?

Answer (score 2):

When you use dot notation for property access on an object `pie.pie_piece` it is looking for a property with the actual name `pie_piece` in the `pie` object.

To use the value of `pie_piece` you will want to use bracket notation

```
pie[pie_piece]
```

more on [property access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Answer (score 0):

You can access elements of an object by using the notation `object['element']`. So in this case you could do something like `pie[pie_piece]` if pie_piece is `welfare`, `health`, or `state_pensions`.

```
    var pie = {

    welfare: {
        title: "Welfare",
        percentage : 24,
        point: 0,
        color: '#601C6B'
    },

    health: {
        title: "Health",
        percentage : 20,
        point: 0,
        color: '#FFAA97'
    },

    state_pensions: {
        title: "State pensions",
        percentage : 13,
        point: 0,
        color: "#9C9C9C"
    }
}


$('.pie_item').click(function(){

var pie_piece = $(this).text();

console.log("this is " + pie_piece);

$(this).closest(".drop_down_button").find('p').text(pie_piece);

console.log(pie[pie_piece]);

});
```